# create timeseries based on start and end date

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

I have two columns of data, one of timestamp in 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' format and another numeric column with number of orders.

How can I define an hourly time series of the 'no of orders' column with a start date & end date.

I tried the below code but got the error '**invalid time series parameters specified**'

```
OFS_ts <-ts(data = temp$OFS_transformed,start = temp$DateHour[1],end = temp$DateHour[nrow(temp)])
```

OFS_transformed -> number of sales orders at that time-stamp (the data to be converted into time series )

DateHour -> timestamp in the format '2015-10-25 18:00:00'

temp -> dataset

```
OFS_transformed    DateHour

6.89871446      2015-10-30 00:00:00
6.1548579376    2015-10-30 01:00:00
5.9889612322    2015-10-30 02:00:00
6.678342022     2015-10-30 03:00:00
5.7333410385    2015-10-30 04:00:00
6.8741984193    2015-10-30 05:00:00
5.4806386163    2015-10-30 06:00:00
```

Comment: please provide example data and expected output.

Comment: @mtoto .. I have added sample dataset. Expected output is to have a timeseries of OFS_transformed column based on timestamps in DateHour column (start & end date) with a frequency of 1 hour. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the function `hour` in the package `lubridate`? You could use it to assign an hourly ID to each instance, then use any one of many grouping and summarizing functions to do the next step.

Comment: @ulfelder .. thanks for the comment, yes I am aware of the hour() function from lubridate.. But I need to include the dates also in the timeseries so as to get a daily/weekly/monthly overview also.. for eg: whether Monday 9 AM saw more sales compared to Tuesday 9 AM.... I am sort of struck with this part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the function `ts()`, you need to define the `frequency=` argument which specifies the periodicity of your data. This depends on the type of timeseries, and the frequency of observations. It is also possible to have multiple seasonalities.

For example your hourly data can have a daily, (`frequency=24`), weekly (`frequency=24×7=168`) or monthly seasonality (`frequency=24×30=720`). Note that it is enough if you only specify `frequency=` and `start=`.

```
# Daily seasonality
OFS_ts <-ts(data = df$OFS_transformed,
             start = min(df$DateHour),
             frequency = 24)
```

One drawback of `ts()` is that date values are represented numerically:

```
> plot(OFS_ts)
```

[image]

A perhaps better option is the function `xts()` from the same-named package, where the `frequency =` argument is not even mandatory:

```
library(xts)
OFS_xts <- xts(temp$OFS_transformed, 
                order.by = temp$DateHour)
plot(OFS_xts)
```

[image]

An `xts` object *extends* the class `ts`, so all functions that work with `ts` objects, will also work with `xts`.

Comment: Thanks , I will give it a try & will update here.. by the way, any idea why my code above doesn't work ?

Comment: probably because you haven't specified `frequency = `

Comment: Even I also think so.. how can I specify the frequency as 1 hour. I know how to specify for year/month/quarter etc but not for hour. Will you please help me with it.

Comment: thank you very much.. I could create the xts object but when I run your code for ts object, I still get the error that "invalid time series parameters specified" . any idea ? by the way, frequency(OFS_xts) gives  0.0002777778, what does it mean ?

Comment: please `dput()` your data, because as of now the error cannot be reproduced.

Comment: It seems " OFS_ts <-msts(data = temp$OFS_transformed,seasonal.periods = c(24,168),start=temp$DateHour[1]) " seems to be working (from forecast package). with (24,168) we can mention multi-seasonal pattern (hourly+ weekly in this case)